# Why does the Conditional format Not take until I click inside the formula bar?

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have the formula generated in VBA for the conditional format as follows

```
'''Range("H2").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=H2<F2"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16776961
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=H2>=F2"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
    .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Selection.Copy
Range("H3:H4000").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
Application.CutCopyMode = False'''
```

When I format this way the result does not take until I click into the formula entry field for that cell, and then click out of it. See pictures for formula, how it looks before I click into, and how it looks after I click in and out.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJXPP.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like you have numbers stored as text in column F.

Comment: I do not see any flags? Is there a way to view this or mass convert the column?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885

Comment: That does it. I have no idea how or why those stored to text. Thank you.

Comment: As a side note, you can use `--` inside your formula to coerce the text to number: `=--H2<--F2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The result does not take until I click into the formula entry field for that cell, and then click out of it."

This is often a symptom of numbers stored as text.

You can convert them to true numbers, using this [paste-special trick](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-numbers-stored-as-text-to-numbers-40105f2a-fe79-4477-a171-c5bad0f0a885).

Or you can coerce them to numbers in the conditional formatting rule using the double unary `--`:

```
=--H2<--F2
```